# Limit of alternating series test that does not equal 0

Tags: calculus

In the test for the alternating series, if the limit does not equal 0, can I conclude that the series is divergent? Or does the alternating series test only test for convergence of a series? Meaning I can't make any assumptions for limits that are not equal to 0.

Thanks!

Comment: If the limit of the terms is not $0$, the series is divergent.